# XML parsing in python issue using elementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree, python-3.8, python-3.9

I  need to parse a soap response and convert to a text file. I am trying to parse the values as detailed below. I am using ElementTree in python

I have the below xml response which I need to parse

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tmf854="tmf854.v1" xmlns:alu="alu.v1">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <tmf854:header>
      <tmf854:activityName>query</tmf854:activityName>
      <tmf854:msgName>queryResponse</tmf854:msgName>
      <tmf854:msgType>RESPONSE</tmf854:msgType>
      <tmf854:senderURI>https:/destinationhost:8443/tmf854/services</tmf854:senderURI>
      <tmf854:destinationURI>https://localhost:8443</tmf854:destinationURI>
      <tmf854:activityStatus>SUCCESS</tmf854:activityStatus>
      <tmf854:correlationId>1</tmf854:correlationId>
      <tmf854:communicationPattern>MultipleBatchResponse</tmf854:communicationPattern>
      <tmf854:communicationStyle>RPC</tmf854:communicationStyle>
      <tmf854:requestedBatchSize>1500</tmf854:requestedBatchSize>
      <tmf854:batchSequenceNumber>1</tmf854:batchSequenceNumber>
      <tmf854:batchSequenceEndOfReply>true</tmf854:batchSequenceEndOfReply>
      <tmf854:iteratorReferenceURI>http://9195985371165397084</tmf854:iteratorReferenceURI>
      <tmf854:timestamp>20220915222121.472+0530</tmf854:timestamp>
    </tmf854:header>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <queryResponse xmlns="alu.v1">
      <queryObjectData>
        <queryObject>
          <name>
            <tmf854:mdNm>AMS</tmf854:mdNm>
            <tmf854:meNm>CHEERLAVANCHA_281743</tmf854:meNm>
            <tmf854:ptpNm>/type=NE/CHEERLAVANCHA_281743</tmf854:ptpNm>
          </name>
          <vendorExtensions>
            <package>
              <NameAndStringValue>
                <tmf854:name>hubSubtendedStatus</tmf854:name>
                <tmf854:value>NONE</tmf854:value>
              </NameAndStringValue>
              <NameAndStringValue>
                <tmf854:name>productAndRelease</tmf854:name>
                <tmf854:value>DF.6.1</tmf854:value>
              </NameAndStringValue>
              <NameAndStringValue>
                <tmf854:name>adminUserName</tmf854:name>
                <tmf854:value>isadmin</tmf854:value>
              </NameAndStringValue>
              <NameAndStringValue>
           </package>
          </vendorExtensions>
        </queryObject>
      </queryObjectData>
     </queryResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to use the below code snippet.

```
parser = ElementTree.parse("response.txt")
            root = parser.getroot()
            inventoryObjectData = root.find(".//{alu.v1}queryObjectData")
            for inventoryObject in inventoryObjectData:
                for device in inventoryObject:
                    if (device.tag.split("}")[1]) == "me":
                        vendorExtensionsNames = []
                        vendorExtensionsValues = []
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}mdNm") is not None:
                            mdnm = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}mdNm").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}meNm") is not None:
                            menm = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}meNm").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}userLabel") is not None:
                            userlabel = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}userLabel").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}resourceState") is not None:
                            resourcestate = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}resourceState").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}location") is not None:
                            location = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}location").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}manufacturer") is not None:
                            manufacturer = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}manufacturer").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}productName") is not None:
                            productname = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}productName").text
                        if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}version") is not None:
                            version = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}version").text
                        vendorExtensions = device.find("vendorExtensions")
                        vendorExtensionsNamesElements = vendorExtensions.findall(".//{tmf854.v1}name")
                        for i in vendorExtensionsNamesElements:
                            vendorExtensionsNames.append(i.text.strip())
                         vendorExtensionsValuesElements = vendorExtensions.findall(".//{tmf854.v1}value")
                        for i in vendorExtensionsValuesElements:
                            vendorExtensionsValues.append(str(i.text or "").strip())

                        alu = ""
                        for i in vendorExtensions:
                            if i.attrib:
                                if alu == "":
                                    alu = i.attrib.get("{alu.v1}name")
                                else:
                                    alu = alu + "|" + i.attrib.get("{alu.v1}name")
```

The issue is that The below code is not able to find the 'vendorExtensions"'. Please help here.

```
vendorExtensions = device.find("vendorExtensions")
```

Have tried the  below as well

```
vendorExtensions = device.find(".//queryObject/vendorExtensions")
```

Comment: It helps if your example code and data are runnable: your example data has syntactic errors that render it invalid. Your code presumes the existence of an `<inventoryObjectData>` element, but not such element exists in your example data.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, but that XML file is still invalid. Try pasting it into an XML validator (e.g., https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator). Additionally, your code is still looking for an `<inventoryObjectData>` element that **does not exist** in your example XML data.

Comment: Hello. That was a typo. HAve corrected it to 'queryObjectData'. But actually, this is the repsonse on which I need to work . It is a soap response which I am trying to parse.

Comment: The XML is still invalid. Please see the link in my previous comment for an XML validator so that you can correct that problem. If the data or code you present in your question is not syntactically correct it makes it difficult for people to help you.

Comment: Note that XML does not necessarily need to be *valid*, but it must be *well-formed*. These are different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document declares a default namespace of `alu.v1`:

```
<queryResponse xmlns="alu.v1">
...
</queryResponse>
```

Any attribute without an explicit namespace is in the `alu.v1` namespace. You need to qualify your attribute name appropriately:

```
vendorExtensions = device.find("{alu.v1}vendorExtensions")
```

---

While the above is a real problem with your code that needs to be corrected (the Wikipedia entry on [XML namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) may be useful reading if you're unfamiliar with how namespaces work), there are also some logic problems with your code.

Let's drop the big list of conditionals from the code and see if it's actually doing what we think it's doing. If we run this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

parser = ElementTree.parse("data.xml")
root = parser.getroot()
queryObjectData = root.find(".//{alu.v1}queryObjectData")
for queryObject in queryObjectData:
    for device in queryObject:
        print(device.tag)
```

Then using your sample data (once it has been corrected to be syntactically valid), we see as output:

```
{alu.v1}name
{alu.v1}vendorExtensions
```

Your search for the `{alu.v1}vendorExtensions` element will never succeed before the thing on which you're trying to search (the `device` variable) **is** the thing you're trying to find.

Additionally, the conditional in your loop...

```
if (device.tag.split("}")[1]) == "me":
```

...will never match (there is no element in the entire document for which `tag.split("}")[1] == "me"` is `True`).

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but here's are some thoughts:

- Given your example data, you probably don't want that `for device in inventoryObject:` loop
- We can drastically simplify your code by replacing that long block of conditionals with a list of attributes in which we are interested and then a `for` loop to extract them.
- Rather than assigning a bunch of individual variables, we can build up a dictionary with the data from the `queryObject`

That might look like:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import json

attributeNames = [
    "mdNm",
    "meNm",
    "userLabel",
    "resourceState",
    "location",
    "manufacturer",
    "productName",
    "version",
]

parser = ElementTree.parse("data.xml")
root = parser.getroot()
queryObjectData = root.find(".//{alu.v1}queryObjectData")
for queryObject in queryObjectData:
    device = {}

    for name in attributeNames:
        if (value := queryObject.find(f".//{{tmf854.v1}}{name}")) is not None:
            device[name] = value.text

    vendorExtensions = queryObject.find("{alu.v1}vendorExtensions")
    extensionMap = {}

    for extension in vendorExtensions.findall(".//{alu.v1}NameAndStringValue"):
        extname = extension.find("{tmf854.v1}name").text
        extvalue = extension.find("{tmf854.v1}value").text
        extensionMap[extname] = extvalue

    device["vendorExtensions"] = extensionMap

    print(json.dumps(device, indent=2))
```

Given your example data, this outputs:

```
{
  "mdNm": "AMS",
  "meNm": "CHEERLAVANCHA_281743",
  "vendorExtensions": {
    "hubSubtendedStatus": "NONE",
    "productAndRelease": "DF.6.1",
    "adminUserName": "isadmin"
  }
}
```

---

An alternate approach, in which we just transform each `queryObject` into a dictionary, might look like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import json


def localName(ele):
    return ele.tag.split("}")[1]


def etree_to_dict(t):
    if list(t):
        d = {}
        for child in t:
            if localName(child) == "NameAndStringValue":
                d.update(dict([[x.text.strip() for x in child]]))
            else:
                d.update({localName(child): etree_to_dict(child) for child in t})
        return d
    else:
        return t.text.strip()


parser = ElementTree.parse("data.xml")
root = parser.getroot()
queryObjectData = root.find(".//{alu.v1}queryObjectData") or []
for queryObject in queryObjectData:
    d = etree_to_dict(queryObject)
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

This will output:

```
{
  "name": {
    "mdNm": "AMS",
    "meNm": "CHEERLAVANCHA_281743",
    "ptpNm": "/type=NE/CHEERLAVANCHA_281743"
  },
  "vendorExtensions": {
    "package": {
      "hubSubtendedStatus": "NONE",
      "productAndRelease": "DF.6.1",
      "adminUserName": "isadmin"
    }
  }
}
```

That may or may not be appropriate depending on the structure of your real data and exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I thired this. But it is not able to find the value. It is returning 'None'

Comment: This works just fine for me when I test it, but because your question doesn't include valid example data it's possible I've made an erroneous assumption. Please update your question so that the example data is both valid and contains the elements expected by your script and I'd be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: No. IT is not working for me. For the input and as per the code, it is not able to find the {alu.v1}vendorExtensions. Did you place it in a different indent ?

Comment: The example XML data you've presented in your question is invalid. Please fix it, and I will take a closer look.

Comment: I have updated the whole response. The only difference is that currently, we re receiving a single queryObject. But later we will receive many

Comment: I've updated this answer to address additional issues with your code.